# Not throwing exception while xpath is not available on page using selenium and python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

If xpath is not available on a page then it should throw exception but it breaks the whole program with errors.

I have loaded complete page using selenium and then I am trying to click on all read-more link but not working.

**Page Link**
https://www.zomato.com/ncr/k3-jw-marriott-new-delhi-igi-airport-new-delhi

**sample code**

```
xpath_content=".//*[@id='reviews-container']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/span"
temp="true"
while temp:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,xpath_content))) 
        urls=driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_content)
        text=urls.text
        if text:
            temp=text  
        print "XPATH read_more=",temp
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_content).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        print driver.title, "no Read more review"
        temp=""
```

**Got Error**

```
 File "zomato_delhi.py", line 31, in read_more_content
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_content).click()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 65, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 402, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 175, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Stacktrace:
at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///tmp/tmpKtHaW3/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:9587)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///tmp/tmpKtHaW3/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12257)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpKtHaW3/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12274)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpKtHaW3/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12279)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpKtHaW3/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12221)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This worked for me**

```
xpath_content=".//*[@id='reviews-container']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/span" 
try:
     WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,xpath_content))) 
    driver.execute_script('$("span.read-more").click();') 
except TimeoutException:
    print driver.title, "no Read more review"
```

**No need any loop**

`driver.execute_script('$("span.read-more").click();')`

it will click on all read-more links on a page.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the while loop

It's working after removing the While loop

Comment: No, this will not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I can only comment on the XPath expression, not on the Selenium code. Your expression is hopelessly complicated, why not simply use

```
//span[@class = "read-more"]
```

to identify the correct span element? Test this e.g. in the Web Console of Firefox or Chrome, using

```
$x('//span[@class = "read-more"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath_content)))
```

with

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath_content)))
```

Comment: it does not give me any error but did not click on all **read-more** links on a page

Comment: @user3902208: maybe because of errors in your xpath expressions ? But the question was about the error, it wasn't ?